# Reverse scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scroller

I am working on a jquery timeline. I need to make the main content draggable and move the handlebar in relation to the the distance dragged. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

http://kuficgraphics.com/dev/NASA/timeline/

Comment: Did you tried to do this by using CSS? [overflow: auto; width: 300px; height: 100px]?

Comment: Have you checked out [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) and the slider control? (or the [side scroll](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll))

Answer (score 0):

[Dragscrollable jQuery plugin](http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html)

You can either use it or customize it for your needs. (check license support for modification)